# When will $AB$ and $B$ have the same column space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-calculus

Suppose $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ with $n>m$ and $rank(B)=m$.

Now given $B$, I would like to find all $A$'s such that $AB$ and $B$ have the same column space.

A trivial solution would be $A=I_n$, but I would like to find all solutions (explicitly if possible? or any necessary and sufficient condition that $A$ need to satisify?)

Comment: Basically, $A$ must take the image of $B$ to itself. In particular, $\textrm{im}(B)$ is an invariant subspace of $A$.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ the vector space of matrices of size $n \times m$ over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Mysterygirl Yes you are right.

Comment: @subrosar thanks that's a general answer, but is there any more explicit way to state the condition / solution?

Comment: Another trivial solution of course is any matrix $A$ such that the columns of $B$ are all eigenvectors of $A$. This gives a sufficient condition for $A$, but gives only a subset of the general solution given by @subrosar. I don't believe there is a more explicit way to state it.

Comment: @user1551 thanks! That's very helpful! So if both $A$ and $B$ are full rank, then the condition becomes $B(B^* B)^{-1}B^*=AB(B^* B)^{-1}B^* A^{-1}$? Does this imply any explicit way to construct $A$?

Comment: @user1551, I think I now I understand the notations. I just dont get why this construction is related to the condition you state. Could you explain why such construction would lead to the desired result?

Comment: @user1551, specifically I don't quite understand why $U^\top AU=X\oplus Y$ for some $X\in GL_m(\mathbb{R})$ implies AB and B have the same column space?

Comment: I have some initial ideas. Let $v_1,...,v_n$ be the column vectors of B, and $\phi$ be the linear operator over $\mathbb{R}^n$ which receives $A$ as a matrix of it with respect to the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then ${\rm rank} (AB)={\rm rank}(B)$ means $\dim <v_1,...,v_m>=\dim<\phi(v_1),...,\phi(v_m)>$ This makes me think that $\phi_{|B}$ can be an isomorphism from $B$ to $B$... (I use $B$ to denote the column space of $B$ too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and $B=USV^T$ be a singular value decomposition. Since $U$ and $V$ are nonsingular,
\begin{aligned}
&\operatorname{range}(B)=\operatorname{range}(AB)\\
&\Leftrightarrow\operatorname{range}(U^TBV)=\operatorname{range}(U^TABV)\\
&\Leftrightarrow\operatorname{range}(S)=\operatorname{range}(U^TAUS).\\
\end{aligned}
As $B$ has rank $m$, the image of $S$ is $\operatorname{span}\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_m\}$. Therefore $\operatorname{range}(B)=\operatorname{range}(AB)$ if and only if the linear span of the first $m$ columns of $U^TAU$ is identical to $\operatorname{span}\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_m\}$. This means $U^TAU$ is in the form of $\pmatrix{X&\ast\\ 0&\ast}$. Hence the general solution is given by $A=U\pmatrix{X&\ast\\ 0&\ast}U^T$ where $X\in GL_m(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Thanks! That's a neat answer!

Comment: Wow, so I guess the answer nearly correctly (just missing the matrices U and U^T)! Are you using the orthogonal diagnosed form of B?

Comment: @Mysterygirl Sorry, I don't know what form you are referring to. In my answer, $B=USV^T$ is a singular value decomposition.

Comment: Ah, I mean $USV^T$